# result not getting using multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2

The `tool_id` given here are `7` and `5` and the `quantity` selected are `3` and `2` respectively.When i select the `tool_id` of `7` i need to get changed `quantity` of that `tool_id` to `3` and when i select the `tool_id` of `5` i need to get changed `quantity` of that `tool_id` to `2`.need to change as per the id selected please help me to solve my problem
Here is my code

```
$tool_id = array(7,5); //array of id
$quantity = array(3,2);//array or qty
$updateArray = array();
for($x = 0; $x < count($tool_id); $x++){
    $updateArray[] = array(
        'id'=>$tool_id[$x],
        'available' => $quantity[$x]
    );
}      
$this->db->update_batch('tbl_tools',$updateArray,'id');
```

please help me to solve my problem

```
public function edit_available()
{
  $tool_id=array(7,5);
  var_dump($tool_id);
  $quantity=array(3,2);
  var_dump($quantity);
  $data = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($tool_id as $t){
  $data[$i]['id'] = $t;
  $data[$i]['available'] = $quantity[$i];
  $i++;
  }
  $query=$this->db->update_batch('tbl_tools', $data, 'id');
     var_dump($query);
 if($query)
 {
        return true;
 }
 else
 {
        return false;
 }
```

}

here am having two tables namely `tbl_tools` and `tbl_tool_use`.
the `tbl_tools` looks as follows

```
id  name            quantity    available   type        
5   cutting player     5          5        engineer     
6   reflectors         2          2        team     
7   spanner            8          8        engineer     
8   tester             4          4        team
```

`tbl_tool_use` looks as follows

```
id  user_id     type      tool_id   quantity    available               start_date  end_date
201  26        engineer     7,5     3,2        8available,5available    2016-12-30
```

here in the table `tbl_tool_use` the tool_id selected are 7 and 5 and for that the quantity selected are 3 and 2 respectively while inserting this data in to the this table at the same time my `tbl_tools` table should get reduced like this

```
id  name            quantity    available   type        
5   cutting player     5          2        engineer     
6   reflectors         2          2        team     
7   spanner            8          3        engineer     
8   tester             4          4        team
```

this is the concept for that am using that code

Comment: get the index of `$t_id` for the provided tool_id, then change the qty array using that index

Comment: like what i did here

Comment: anybody have any idea

Comment: I have already mentioned. Try with that idea

Comment: i have tried a lot and am new to this if you dont mind can you help me by showing an example with my code

Comment: here am getting an error of  `Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: id

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php` and `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

```
    $tool_id = array(7,5); //array of id
    $quantity = array(3,2);//array or qty
    $arrayCombine = array_combine($tool_id, $quantity);
    // var_dump($arrayCombine);
    foreach ($arrayCombine as $key => $value) {
        $updateArray[] = array(
            'id'=>$key,
            'available' => $value
        );

    }
    $this->db->update_batch('tbl_tools',$updateArray,'id');
```

Comment: am getting this error after usingyour code `One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.`

Comment: Dude! your code logic is totally different from my code. I have  used array_combine() function for the achieve your requirement. In my foreach you will get the  proper key & value in $updateArray for update in update_batch function. See the code logic which is more important. Cheers!!

Comment: yaa am k with that but am telling you that the result produced is same

Comment: can you please little more clear with your requirement ? Like what kind of array you want for update ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131871/discussion-between-niklesh-chauhan-and-user-777).